# Is Sampajañña and Dhamma vicaya related?

Tags: vipassana, satipatthana

Does [Sampajañña](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampaja%C3%B1%C3%B1a) and [Dhamma vicaya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhamma_vicaya) have an overlap. What is the relationship between the two? What is the differences? Is Sampajañña a result of dhamma vicaya? Do you need Sampajañña for dhamma vicaya?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the stock passage defining Sama-Sati, right mindfulness, sampajanna is mentioned:

> And what is right mindfulness? There is the case where a monk remains
>   focused on the body in & of itself — ardent, **alert**, & mindful —
>   putting aside greed & distress with reference to the world. He remains
>   focused on feelings in & of themselves... the mind in & of itself...
>   mental qualities in & of themselves — ardent, alert, & mindful —
>   putting aside greed & distress with reference to the world. This is
>   called right mindfulness.
>
> Katamā cāvuso sammāsati: idhāvuso bhikkhu kāye kāyānupassī viharati
>   ātāpī **sampajāno** satimā vineyya loke abhijjhādomanassaṃ. Vedanāsu
>   vedanānupassī viharati ātāpī sampajāno satimā vineyya loke abhijjhā
>   domanassaṃ. Citte cittānupassī viharati ātāpī sampajāno satimā vineyya
>   loke abhijjhā domanassaṃ. Dhammesu dhammānupassī viharati ātāpī
>   sampajāno satimā vineyya loke abhijjhā domanassaṃ. Ayaṃ vuccatāvuso
>   sammāsati.

(http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.141.than.html)

Thus a person who possesses right mindfulness also has Sampajanna. Dhamma Vicaya however, is not so closely related to mindfulness. Dhamma Vicaya is a result of mindfulness, not a part of it. Mindfulness is the first of the seven factors of enlightenment and Dhamma Vicaya is the second, and in the Anapanasati Sutta they are presented in sequence:

> "[1] On whatever occasion the monk remains focused on the body in & of
>   itself — ardent, alert, & mindful — putting aside greed & distress
>   with reference to the world, on that occasion his mindfulness is
>   steady & without lapse. When his mindfulness is steady & without
>   lapse, then mindfulness as a factor for awakening becomes aroused. He
>   develops it, and for him it goes to the culmination of its
>   development.
>
> "[2] Remaining mindful in this way, he examines, analyzes, & comes to
>   a comprehension of that quality with discernment. When he remains
>   mindful in this way, examining, analyzing, & coming to a comprehension
>   of that quality with discernment, then analysis of qualities as a
>   factor for awakening becomes aroused. He develops it, and for him it
>   goes to the culmination of its development.

(http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.118.than.html)

Comment: Great content. Looking forward to more participation and content from your.